# Hosting my own SVN repositories

Tags: web-hosting, subversion

I've been experimenting with `Google Code` and `Sourceforge` and the like, and am happy with what I've found. The main problem with them, is that you have to have your project be open source to use them, so anybody can edit them.

So... is there some way I can have my own svn repositories on [my own server?](http://theadamgaskins.com/) I have FTP access, cpanel, and all that. If it helps any:

```
    Operating system    Linux
    cPanel Version      11.26.20
    Architecture        x86_64
    MySQL version       5.0.91-community-log
    Apache version      2.2.13
    PHP version         5.2.11
    cPanel Pro          1.0 (RC1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Installing your own SVN server will be just a pain. At the end of the day **you are programmer who wants to develop code and NOT waste time playing with installations of SVN repository on some local/remote/shared server.**

You can find many online solutions that offers preinstalled and ready to use SVN repository. Some are **very cheap**, and **many of them provides a free acoount** for personal use without forcing you to make your project open source.

Some suggestions:

- http://beanstalkapp.com/pricing
- http://unfuddle.com/about/tour/plans
- http://bitbucket.org/plans

Beside prices and your considerations, you can find many CODERs' suggestions at:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69384/opinion-of-hosted-svn-providers
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999/could-you-recommend-a-good-free-project-hosting-website
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465/easysimple-online-source-control

Comment: Partially, I wanted to do this just to have the satisfaction of saying "I host my own SVN server!" It would also be useful, but thats the main reason.

Comment: @TheAdamGaskins: useful for what? I think for a coder/webmaster is definitely more useful spending that time reading and understanding some radomly choosen questions posted here or on stackoverflow.com

Comment: Usefull in my personal programming projects

Answer (score 1):

You would need to install subversion. It sounds like your might be using shared hosting which so installing and configuring subversion on your own server might not be possible. I would recommend you check out Beanstalk. You push changes to your server, to create a continuous integration setup. Also the basic account is free and doesn't require your project to be open source :)

http://beanstalkapp.com/

Comment: I am using shared hosting... the only people I share it with is my Dad though.

Answer (score 1):

Are you on a web host? Some offer Subversion out of the box - [Dreamhost](http://www.dreamhost.com/) does, that's how I got started. They make it easy to create and administer SVN repos.

If you have SSH access, you may be able to install SVN yourself, if permitted by your host.

Also, I'll suggest that installing and managing SVN yourself is a bit of a hassle. Some companies provide project hosting - [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/) is one, I use them now for my SVN repos. They make it even easier!

Comment: Yep, I am. I use in-motion hosting.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [github](http://www.github.com) also do SVN hosting as well as being able to port over from SVN

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post that covers SVN installation on Linux a few months ago. You'll need root access on the server (since you're installing software), as well as SSH access. The guide is written geared toward Ubuntu/Debian, so if you're using something else I would research package management before you start. Additionally, the guide is written with the goal of allowing the user to publish source control to an apache site via a post commit hook... if that's not your goal you can easily skip that part. Without further ado [here's the link](http://brennydoogles.wordpress.com/2011/10/21/using-subversion-to-automatically-publish-your-website/)

Answer (score 0):

yes, as suggested host on github or sourceforge .. but i must confess, subversion is very great and easy to use, also from your windows pc using "tortoise-svn" explorer plugin.

for your own personal use you could:

install subeversion by:

apt-get install subversion

go to the "store" directory ( fe. cd /mnt/svn_store ) and create a repo by:

svnadmin create --fs-type=bdb ./myrepo

the go into that repo and edit svnserve.conf and passwd file. just a view lines to uncomment for basic authentication ....but some reading of documentation would be required.....

edit: forget all that, i overread that you are not root ...